# Javascript WebSocket: Receiving messages from discord

Tags: javascript, c#, html, websocket, discord

So. I have a app that communicates with Javascript with a WebView2 Object, in C# WinForms. However, Most of the handling messages is done in javascript/html of course, so i setup a websocket, and it somewhat works? My and ONLY my messages content(s) are being shown, like, if i send a message, then it'll log it in the console, with the profile picture and all. But if someone else sends a message, then it'll log the profile picture and name, but not the message content? And then the websocket closes. My token is valid as well.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=9&encoding=json");
var interval = 0;

payload = {
    op: 2
    , d: {
        token: ""
        , intents: 512
        , properties: {
            $os: "linux", // this works fine
            $browser: "chrome"
            , $device: "chrome"
        , }
    , }
, };

ws.addEventListener("open", function open(x) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
});

ws.addEventListener("message", function incoming(data) {
    var x = data.data;
    var payload = JSON.parse(x);
    
    const {
        t
        , event
        , op
        , d
    } = payload;
    
    switch (op) {
    case 10:
        const {
            heartbeat_interval
        } = d;
        setInterval(() => {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                op: 2
                , d: null
            }));
        }, heartbeat_interval);
        
        break;
    }
    
    switch (t) {
        // yes targetChannelId is CORRECT.
    case "MESSAGE_CREATE":
        if (d.channel_id === targetChannelId) {
            var final = {
                author: d.author.username
                , content: d.content
                , image: `${d.author.avatar ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${d.author.id}/${d.author.avatar}.png` : 'N/A'}`
            }
            
            appendMessageWithFrame(final); // call
            console.log(d); 
            // this is where i'm confused. d.content is blank when someone else types? but when i type its not blank??
            console.log(`${d.author.username}: ${d.content}, Avatar URL: ${d.author.avatar ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${d.author.id}/${d.author.avatar}.png` : 'N/A'}`);
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

Tried double-checking my token, it was obviously correct, checked targetChannelId, ALSO correct, checked the `d` array, still, correct, until someone else types, then d.content is empty and the websocket breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct, you're just missing the [message content intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-content-intent). Message Content [was made a privileged intent in 2022](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ), and thus has to be enabled both in your app, and in the Discord Developer Dashboard.

Comment: thank you, intents were actually the problem. You're a life saver!